# I have a question on using a split() method and the data's format (solved, uploading as memo)

Tags: python, split

I have made a variable like below,

```
data = '''
hello my name is mj
and I like reading novels and webtoons
nice meeting you all!
'''
```

and used data.split('\n') to split by sentences.

The data came up like,

```
['', 'hello my name is mj', 'and I like reading novels and webtoons', 'nice meeting you all!', '']
```

At the above list, why is there double quotations(") in the starting and at the end? Are those single sentence like 'hello my name is mj' and 'and I like ~' tied up as one string? If so, why??

Wait, while writing this question I think I got the answer, it is not just double quotation it is two single quotation written in order. As there is nothing written next to two '''s, so it just made empty string.

Comment: Yes, after the first `'''` there is a new line character (no text before), therefore there's an empty string as first element in your data.

Answer (score 1):

There is `\n` character at the beginning and end of you string, therefore it is also a part of the return value from split. You can do something like this:

```
[x for x in data.split('\n') if x]
```

Using list comprehension with a condition to filter only lines that are not empty.

Answer (score 1):

> ...to split by sentence

There is the native [splitlines](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines) method for this. It is advised to use that method, as it is aware of all kinds of varying encodings for line breaks.

Also, it will not create an extra entry at the end when the input *ends* with a line break like in your example. However, since you have an explicit empty line at the beginning, that one would still be included.

It *might* be a pragmatic solution to just strip your input from surrounding white space:

```
data.strip().splitlines()
```

For your example input, this will evaluate to:

```
[
  'hello my name is mj', 
  'and I like reading novels and webtoons',
  'nice meeting you all!'
]
```